# Reverse Order of Integration Question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Reverse the order of integration of the following integral:

$\int_{0}^{2}$ $\int_{2x}^{4x-x^2}$$dydx$

I'm not quite sure what to do about the term $4x - x^2.$ My understanding for solving these is that they typically require an inversion of the term, however, while it's easy to express $y = 2x$ as $x = \frac{1}{2}y$, it's not possible to define $y = 4x - x^2$ in terms of $x$.What is the key to solving a question like this?

Comment: The key is to draw a diagram. Make sure you really understand what the region looks like. When you do, the new limits are much clearer.

Comment: It's possible to define $y=4x-x^2$ in terms of $x$ and indeed, this is what you've got to do. Use the quadratic formula, if you wish.

Comment: String - the question requires the integral to be reversed. Simon - I have drawn a diagram and understand the region. Daniel - I'll see what I can do, so far I haven't really been able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: @Mock: Then I agree with Simon S! The key is to draw a diagram.

Comment: Okay, so I think that I've managed to get the inversion as $x = \sqrt{4-y} +2$. Looks difficult to solve, but I think I'm on the right track, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Mock: It could be either $+\sqrt{4-y}$ or $-\sqrt{4-y}$. Which one is it this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CAUTION (hot content)**

Here is a spoiler. Do not move your cursor over the blank field below if you do not want to know!

> $$\int_0^4\int_{2-\sqrt{4-y}}^{\tfrac12 y}\ dx\ dy$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is the graph of what your double integral is showing. Since this is a double integral of 1, this is computing the area of the arc-shape made. When the order is $\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$, the limits of integration for $y$ uses variables while the limits of integration for $x$ use constants. Since you want to change it to $\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$, it will be the opposite.

For $\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$ integration, span the curve from the left to the right by solving each equation for $x$. The limits of integration for $x$ will be $0$ to $4$.

$$\int_0^4\int_{2-\sqrt{4-y}}^{\frac12y}1\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$